# How can I filter an array without using a loop in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

Here I am trying to filter only the elements that do not have a substring `world` and store the results back to the same array. What is the correct way to do this in Perl?

```
$ cat test.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = ('hello 1', 'hello 2', 'hello 3', 'world1', 'hello 4', 'world2');

print "@arr\n";
@arr =~ v/world/;
print "@arr\n";

$ perl test.pl
Applying pattern match (m//) to @array will act on scalar(@array) at
test.pl line 7.
Applying pattern match (m//) to @array will act on scalar(@array) at
test.pl line 7.
syntax error at test.pl line 7, near "/;"
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
$
```

I want to pass the array as an argument to a subroutine.

I know one way would be to something like this

```
$ cat test.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = ('hello 1', 'hello 2', 'hello 3', 'world1', 'hello 4', 'world2');
my @arrf;

print "@arr\n";

foreach(@arr) {
    unless ($_ =~ /world/i) {
       push (@arrf, $_); 
    }
}
print "@arrf\n";

$ perl test.pl
hello 1 hello 2 hello 3 world1 hello 4 world2
hello 1 hello 2 hello 3 hello 4
$
```

I want to know if there is a way to do it without the loop (using some simple filtering).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That would be `grep()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = ('hello 1', 'hello 2', 'hello 3', 'world1', 'hello 4', 'world2');
my @narr = ( );

print "@arr\n";
@narr = grep(!/world/, @arr);
print "@narr\n";
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
sub remove_worlds { grep !/world/, @_ }
```

For example:

```
@arrf = remove_worlds @arr;
```

Using `grep` is the most natural fit for your particular problem, but for completeness, you can also do it with [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

```
sub remove_worlds { map /world/ ? () : $_, @_ }
```

It's a bit klunky here, but `map` gives you a hook in case you want to process the filtered elements before discarding them.

Comment: Good to have the ref links here.

Comment: That `!/match/` negative matching syntax was critical. I'd been considering map and other solutions but they all seemed too clunky for perl.

Answer (score 11):

Use `grep`

```
@no_world_for_tomorrow = grep { !/world/ } @feathers;
```

For details, `perldoc -f grep`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) function as:

```
@arrf =  grep(!/world/, @arr);
```

The expression `!/world/` is evaluated for each element of the array `@arr` and a list of elements which which the expression evaluated to be true is returned.

The expression `/world/` searches for the word `world` and is true it's present. And the expression `!/world/` is true if the string `world` is absent.