# How to check if an array has an element that's not Integer?

Tags: perl

For example, I have an array = [1,2,3,4,5,a,#,4]
how can I check if an array has an element that's not integer?
If an array has an element that's not integer than I am planning to fail the script which is die function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I filter an array without using a loop in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960028/how-can-i-filter-an-array-without-using-a-loop-in-perl) Couple that with the integer case from [How can I tell if a variable was a numeric value in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647/how-do-i-tell-if-a-variable-has-a-numeric-value-in-perl)

Answer (score 2):

Type::Tiny provides a quick method (`all`) to check if all elements in a list match a specific type consrtaint.

```perl
use strict; use warnings; use feature qw( say );
use Types::Common qw( Int PositiveInt );

my @array = ( 1, 2, 3, "foo" );

if ( not Int->all( @array ) ) {
  say "They're not all integers";
}

if ( PositiveInt->all( @array ) ) {
  say "They're all positive integers";
}

# Another way to think about it:

my $NonInteger = ~Int;

if ( $NonInteger->any( @array ) ) {
  say "There's at least one non-integer";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If quick&dirty is good enough:

```
my @a = (1,2,3,-4,0,5,4," -32   ");
die if grep { !defined or !/^\s*-?\d+\s*$/ } @a;
```

This however doesn't handle for example valid integers (in Perl) such as `"1_200_499"` or `"0e0"` well.